Hreflang in Opencart 3.0.3.9
Opencart is a great software for selling online.
However for multi-language sites not perfect.
Installed version 3.0.3.9 (PHP8)
Languages installed are English, German and Dutch.
So in the page source appears the language, for example
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

However this isn't SE friendly, it misses the hreflang.
Is there a solution to fix this, without an extension?
I searched online, but the only solution given is an extension.
Because I don't now the seller, I like to solve the issue in a different way.
Also found some code, but it broke down the shop.
